# PHP - Restricting socket connection period

Tags: php, linux, sockets

I'm fetching data from a socket that pumps data at unknown intervals. There could be nothing for minutes (or even hours) and then tens of thousands of rows can be queued ready for reading.

Because I don't know what to expect, I was hoping to build something that connects for 2-5 seconds slurping in however much it can, irrespective of how much is queued up at the server end.

This is what I have at the moment.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(2);
ini_set('max_input_time', 2);

$timeout       = 3;
$host          = 'data.host.com';
$port          = 6543;
$fp            = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
stream_set_timeout($fp, 2);
if( !$fp ){
  echo "Connection to '$host' failed.\n$errstr ($errno)\n";
  exit;
}

while( !feof($fp) ){
  $xml = trim(fgets($fp));
  if(empty($xml)) continue;
  echo "XML=$xml\n";
}

echo "DONE\n";

function shutdown(){
  echo "SHUTDOWN!\n";
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

However this never finishes at all. The while loop appears to be as infinite as one might expect (out of context). How do I put in and capture some exit/break/kill?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best/correct way to do it, but it *should* work (untested)

```
    $startTime = time();
    $executionTime = 180; //180 Seconds - 2 Minutes

    while( !feof($fp) ){
        if ((time() - $startTime) > $executionTime) {
            //If time has been longer than the execution time, break
            //out of loop
            break;
        }
        $xml = trim(fgets($fp));
        if(empty($xml)) continue;
        echo "XML=$xml\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a mysql connection, if so use the default port. Restricting the socket connection is not advisable unless you can store all transaction in a temp db and push else where at the time alloted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_time = time();
while( !feof($fp) ){
  $xml = trim(fgets($fp));
  if(empty($xml)) continue;
  echo "XML=$xml\n";
  if ( time() - $star_time > 320 ) break;
}
```